# django. The manage.py is not working after migrating mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, django

I install mysql as my database in my django project.
I did makemigration and migrate it on the django.
After that I wanted to try to run the server, but the python manage.py is not working at all even if there is python stored in my computer.
[python_version_in_cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzYD6.png)

I have the screenshot here where it shows no response at all but pip is responding. [django](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV7Fs.png)

This is my computer environment path [computer enviroment path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfySm.png)

When I was installing mysql the mysql/python was failing, is that the problem? any hints?

Comment: "When I was installing mysql the mysql/python was failing.."  Please clarify what was failing.  How did you installed mysql?   Please include as much detail as possible.

Comment: SOLVED, manage.py file was erased somewhat and needed to revert it back

Answer (score 0):

What is the error when running python manage.py runserver? Not knowing that, I could make some guesses.

1. Make sure your models are setup correctly.
2. After you get your models written, you can run `python manage.py makemigrations`
3. Then you need to run `python manage.py migrate` in order for the models to be applied to the database.

Some guidance can be found here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-migrations-python/